# Body property of Outlook email is empty

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm looking into a script that can access an Outlook folder and read the content of the email. I hope (don't know how yet) to parse the body to extract a URL from it. However, the body of my email and other messages I've tried it on keeps returning empty.

```
$ol = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$ns = $ol.GETNAMESPACE("MAPI")
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)
$inbox.Items($x).Body
# returns nothing
```

Same result for .HTMLBody and .RTFBody.

Possibly related is that SenderName is blank too. Is it possible that have a corporate IT policy that prevents me from seeing my own message metadata? I'm exploring Powershell because they've disabled VBA in Outlook already.

Comment: The same question is asked here: [How to access body of Outlook email messages from Powershell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38514338/1701026) but I am not sure if the answer is satisfying.

Comment: I'm guessing that `$x` is not a valid number. Try `$inbox.items($inbox.items.count).body` and see if that gets you anything. That gets me my most recent email in my inbox. From there it's just a matter of finding the index that you are looking for.